# Start local server automatically

Tags: sql, sql-server, windows, service, database-administration

I'm using windows (10) and every time I need to use/load a database on my local server (SQL Server) I have to manually start the server on Administrator Tools (local services), which costs me a lot of time, every time I reboot my system the server shuts down (stops) and doesn't start on boot. Is there perhaps a way of automatically starting the server permanently, that could save me a lot of time. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, there is a way. Go to your local Services, find the SQL Server Service and set the Startup type to Automatic.

Like illustrated here:

[image]

Comment: If you find that SQL Server is already set to Automatic, yet is not started, try Automatic (Delayed Start).

Comment: @Rigerta Demini you have saved me a lot of time thank you so much, apparently, the service was set was set to Manual.

Comment: @Sydney happy to help!